# How do to Get current HTML tab in Chrome with c#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I open a webpage with `Process.Start("Chrome.exe", "https://www.google.com/");`
then I wanna save a chrome tab HTML page (google HTML Code) into a string in C#.
how can I do it?

I need specified opened url HTML code and save it to a string. because that webpage contains is changeable every minutes.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) using the following code

```
IWebDriver _driver;
_driver = new ChromeDriver();
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
string pageSource = _driver.PageSource ;
_driver.Close();
```

also you can use the following method that accepts url and returns the html of the url

```
    string LoadHtmlFromUrl(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            string htmlCode;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
            return htmlCode;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Log Exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the benefit of the second approach is that there is no need to start another process and no dependencies on chrome

Comment: With selenium, Yes.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to open the browser to do that, here is an example

```
  static void Maing(string[] args)
  {
        string url = "http://google.com";
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myRequest.Method = "GET";

        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        sr.Close();
        myResponse.Close();
  }
```

You will have the html of the google page in the `result` string.

Comment: thank u but I have to open chrome and go to specified url and copy it's html code. this is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, it may not work at javascript rendering and processing